# How to create RF source in CST Studio

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, pcb-antenna, patch-antenna

I have designed a microstrip patch antenna in CST studio and I want to test its efficiency for energy harvesting. Having followed some youtube videos, I understand creating a waveguide port across the microstrip and ground plane is what you would do to test the antenna normally. However, I want to create an RF source at some distance from the antenna and then analyse how the antenna reacts. How should I go about creating this source?